# Repeating an Input till it is answered Correct

Tags: c, loops, conditional-statements

The concept if very simple. The computer must repeat the question till it recieves a valid response. Here is my current code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
int age;

do{
printf("How old are you?\n");
scanf("%d", &age);


if (age == 32767)

{
    printf("Error, retry: \n");
}

else
{
    printf("Cool.");
    break;

}
}
while(age!=3267);

return (0);
}
```

The if else statement is to catch the exception incase the user types something that is not an integer.

I tried using a do-while loop but it ended up as an infinite loop
I used the do-while loop because I needed to go through that procedure until I get a valid age value.

My output with the current code is:

```
How old are you?
g
Error, retry: 
How old are you?
Error, retry: 
How old are you?
Error, retry: 
How old are you?
Error, retry:
```

It goes like this indefinitely.

It would be great if you could help me out.

Comment: Use `do while` loop.

Comment: " tried using a do-while loop but failed ... " - Why? How? What did you do? This is no coding service. See [ask].

Comment: Thank you Olaf, i have corrected my question.

Comment: Does SO markdown support *facepalm*?

Comment: Sorry? I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: For interactive prompt read *lines*.

Comment: Learn how to properly format source code! That is near unreadable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> - The computer must repeat the question till it recieves a valid response.
> - It *(output)* goes like this indefinitely.

**Reason :**

- The problem is that **you are receiving input only once in your code** and then entering into loop to check for the `age`.
- since age value is not re-assigned after every iteration, if the first intput is `!=32767` it's always wrong and **enters into an infinite loop** or also known as the **odd loop**.

  ```
  scanf("%d", &age); //scans only once

  do //enters loop
  {
      if (age == 32767)
      {
          printf("Error, retry: \n");
      }

      else
      {
          printf("Cool.");
      }
  } while(age!=32767);
  ```

---

> The if else statement is to catch the exception incase the user types something that is not an integer.

- **No**, `if (age == 32767)` would only check if the entered response was equal to `32767` or not.
- From **[@davmac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/388661/davmac)** 's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38409402/repeating-an-output-till-it-is-answered-in-c/38409473#comment64227622_38409473) , you can never check for an input value greater than the maximum value of the `int` variable.
- Instead it'd be better if you would assign a range this way

  ```
   `if (age > 100 || age <0 )`
  ```

---

**Solution :**

to avoid this scan `age` for every iteration and also see the changes I've done :

```
do{

    printf("How old are you?\n");

    if(scanf("%d", &age)==1) //checking if scanf is successful or not
    {

        if (age > 100 || age <0 )
        {
            printf("Error, retry: \n");
        }

        else
        {
            printf("Cool.");
            break; //break loop when correct value is entered
        }
    }

    else //if scanf is unsuccessful 
    {
        char c;
        printf("enter only integers\n");

        do
        {
            scanf("%c",&c);
        }while( c !='\n' && c!= EOF ); //consuming characters
    }

}while(1); //always true
```

Comment: How can `age > max_value_of_int` ever be true? Also why not use `INT_MAX` rather than trying to guess the maximum value? Finally, what if the `scanf` fails (because input is not a number) - and `age` is left in an uninitialised state? Comparing it then invokes undefined behaviour.

Comment: @davmac yes yes! forgot about the int overflow :(, i 'll edit in a while

Comment: This is a good answer however the final solution is an infinite loop

Comment: Oh my gosh! This is amazing! Thank you!! Can you explain to me how the second else statement works? What does E0F mean?

Comment: @davmac i've made changes : I avoided checking for max value of int and also checked for the return value of `scanf()`.. thanks for pointing out :)

Comment: @SyedArafatQureshi the second else statement is entered when you `scanf()` is unsuccessful i.e, when a wrong input is given... so in the second else statement using a `while` loop and a character `c`, I scan in all the data in input stream and make it empty for new entry... EOF stands for end of file.. it's useful while taking input from a file :)

Comment: what's the point making a simple thing more and more complex?

Comment: @Kuldeep1007tanwar "what's the point in making a simple thing more and more correct?" FTFY.

Answer (score 0):

Some important points:

First, Using `scanf` to read an `int` from user input usually allows for whitespace to be entered first:

```
scanf(" %d", &age);
```

In particular this skips over previous new line characters that were input previously and are still buffered.

Second, `scanf` returns a value indicating whether it succeeded or failed, and how many items it matched. **You need to check this return value**:

```
 int r = scanf(" %d", &age);
 if (r == EOF) {
     break;
 }
 if (r == 0) {
     printf("Error, retry: \n");         
 }
```

Third, if `scanf` can't match input it is left in the input buffer. If you don't retrieve it from the buffer, it will simply fail to match again the next time you call `scanf`, ad infinitum. For this reason, `scanf` is not great for handling user input at all. It is better, if possible, to read a single line of input into a buffer (you can use `fgets` for this, if you are careful), and then process the buffer. As a weak alternative, you can force some of the input buffer to be consumed by scanning for a string before you try to read the input value again:

```
 int r = scanf(" %d", &age);
 if (r == EOF) {
     break;
 }
 if (r == 0) {
     printf("Error, retry: \n");
     scanf("%*s"); // match string but suppress assignment
 }
 else {
     printf("Cool.\n");
     break;
 }
```

This modification gets your code to at least halfway-working state.

Answer (score -1):

Use do while Loop. Like:

```
Do{

// your code
Age = // asign value

}while(age>100 && age < 1);
```

So it will repeat until age is entered between 100 and 1. It will stop if it will get age b/w 1 - 100.

Thanks. Hope it will help.

Comment: i think you're trying to do - while(age<=100 && age >= 1);

Comment: @Kuldeep1007tanwar: I don't think so. But the code is wrong nevertheless.